# Easier way to produce HTTPGET REQUEST URI on Android

Tags: android, rest, http-get

I'm trying to make an `HTTPGET` request to a REST server, the URL i need to send contains many parameters:

This is the URI :

`http://darate.free.fr/rest/api.php?rquest=addUser&&login=samuel&&password=0757bed3d74ccc8fc8e67a13983fc95dca209407&&firstname=samuel&&lastname=barbier`

I need to get the Login,password,first, name and last name that the user types, then produce an URI like the once above.

Is there any easy way to create the URI, without concatenate the first part of the URI `http://darate.free.fr/rest/api.php?rquest=addUser` with every `&&parameter:value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use [`Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) for building `Uri`s. It makes sure everything is escaped properly.

My typical code:

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(BASE_URI).buildUpon();
builder.appendPath(REQUEST_PATH);
builder.builder.appendQueryParameter("param1", value);
Uri builtUri = builder.build();
```

Comment: so `builder.builder.appendQueryParameter("param1", value);` adds a `&&param1=value` to the BASE_URI is that right?

Comment: You can call .buildUpon() to get a Builder. Once you have one you can use the methods to build it. Then call builder.build() for the final Uri. It's easier to play around with it and then call the toString() method on the built Uri to see how it encoded everything.

Comment: what `appendPath(REQUEST_PATH)` does?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use webview.posturl shown below

```
 webview.postUrl("http://5.39.186.164/SEBC.php?user="+username));
```

It also worked fine for me to get the username from the database. I hope it will help you.